# show the error and resume the stream

Tags: angular, react-native, stream, rxjs, reactjs-flux

I have a real-time search, but if for some reason the forkJoin fails, everything stops working. Any new words I try to look for after the error do not work. How can I show the error and resume the stream normally so that I can search for other words?

```
this.search$
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .switchMap((query) => Rx.Observable.forkJoin(sources)) // If this fails the search stops working
  .subscribe((results) => console.log(results));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```ts
this.search$
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .switchMap((query) => Rx.Observable.forkJoin(sources)
    // return empty results object, I used an empty array...
    .catch(error => Observable.of([])))
  .subscribe((results) => console.log(results));
```

Notice that `catch()` is on `forkJoin()`, not on `switchMap()`...

Comment: I also need to show the error, put this also inside the catch?